# ModelMapper fields mapping

Tags: java, modelmapper

I'm in trouble with ModelMapper framework. Explain please why I see following behaviour.

I have a following dependency in build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '2.0.0'
```

and a class Customer:

```
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("name", name)
                .add("age", age)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Also I have a mapper:

```
public class CustomerPropertyMap extends PropertyMap<Customer, Customer> {

    private final Condition<String, String> isFred = s -> isFred(s.getSource());

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        when(isFred).map(source.getName()).setName("George");
        map(source.getAge(), destination.getAge());
    }

    boolean isFred(String s) {
        return "Fred".equals(s);
    }
}
```

And a test

```
public class PropertyMapTest {
    CustomerPropertyMap customerPropertyMap = new CustomerPropertyMap();
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    @Before
    public void init() {
        modelMapper.addMappings(customerPropertyMap);
    }

    @Test
    public void fred() {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setAge(40);
        customer.setName("Fred");
        Customer mapped = modelMapper.map(customer, Customer.class);
        System.out.println(mapped);
    }

    @Test
    public void nonFred() {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setAge(40);
        customer.setName("Qwerty");
        Customer mapped = modelMapper.map(customer, Customer.class);
        System.out.println(mapped);
    }
}
```

in fred() method output is "Customer{name=Fred, age=40}" in nonFred("Customer{name=null, age=40}"). Can you explain me why? Why I don't see output "George" in first method?

Answer (score 1):

**when** is used for  **Conditional mapping** between the the source type's and the destination type

In your case is name mapped only when condition is met "Fred".equals(name)